# If $a_k\geqslant 0$ and $\sum a_k \in \mathbf{R}$ then $\liminf_{k\to \infty} ka_k =0$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

In all of the examples I see online, it assumes that the sequence is monotone. And if it is we can prove the stronger statement of

$$ka_k \to 0$$

using *Cauchy Condensation*. But I only need to show that

$$\liminf_{k\to \infty} k a_k =0.$$

I am perplexed by the significance of the infinum here. Here is what I know. Since $\sum a_k \in \mathbf{R}$ I know that $a_k \to 0$ so that $\{a_k \}$ has a monotone decreasing *sub*-sequence, call it $\{a_{k_j}\}$. Now I can show that

$$k_j a_{k_j} \to 0$$

but what does that say of the original sequence $\{a_k\}$? Do we need monotonicity to conclude that $ka_k \to 0$ as $k\to \infty$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, we cannot deduce that $\lim_{n\to\infty}na_n=0$ directly from $a_n\geq0$ and $\sum a_n<+\infty,$ but without the assumption that $\{a_n\}$ is decreasing. Actually, the sequence $$1,0,0,1/4,0,0,0,0,1/9,0,\ldots,1/16,0,\ldots$$ is an example which shows that $\lim_{n\to\infty}na_n=0$ fails. However, it is almost direct to get $\liminf_{n\to\infty}na_n=0.$ To see this, we suppose that $$\liminf_{n\to\infty}na_n>\delta_0>0.$$ Then, there exists $N_0\in\mathbf N_+$ such that $na_n>\delta_0$ for any $n>N_0.$ Thus, a contradiction is obtained as following $$\sum_{n>N_0}a_n>\delta_0\sum_{n>N_0}\frac1n=+\infty.$$

Comment: This is exactly the logic I was looking for. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If $\liminf_na_n=a>0$, then there is $n_0$ such that $n\geq n_0$ implies $na_n>\frac{a}{2}$, that is
$$\frac{1}{n}\leq \frac{2}{a}a_n,\qquad n\geq n_0$$
The divergence of $\sum_n\frac{1}{n}$ implies that of $\sum_na_n$